# When I add image in quill editor using base64 then release app show grey screen

Tags: android, flutter, base64

I used Flutter quill 1.6.4 in flutter android app.

When I add image using base64 then it working fine debug app but in release app it show grey screen.

Bellow show my flutter doctor output

[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.2, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.1052], locale en-IN)
• Flutter version 2.2.2 at C:\flutter_sdk\flutter_windows_2.2.2-stable
• Framework revision d79295af24 (7 weeks ago), 2021-06-11 08:56:01 -0700
• Engine revision 91c9fc8fe0
• Dart version 2.13.3
• Pub download mirror https://pub.flutter-io.cn
• Flutter download mirror https://storage.flutter-io.cn

Bellow show my output from release app.

```
I/flutter (31392): #0      _RegExp._ExecuteMatch (dart:core-patch/regexp_patch.dart)
I/flutter (31392): #1      isBase64 (package:string_validator/src/validator.dart)
I/flutter (31392): #2      _defaultEmbedBuilder (package:flutter_quill/src/widgets/editor.dart)
I/flutter (31392): #3      TextLine.build (package:flutter_quill/src/widgets/text_line.dart)
I/flutter (31392): #4      StatelessElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart)
I/flutter (31392): #5      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart)
I/flutter (31392): #6      StatelessElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart)
I/flutter (31392): #7      _TextLineElement._updateChild (package:flutter_quill/src/widgets/text_line.dart)
I/flutter (31392): #8      _TextLineElement.update (package:flutter_quill/src/widgets/text_line.dart)
I/flutter (31392): #9      RenderObjectElement.updateChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart)
I/flutter (31392): #10     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart)
I/flutter (31392): #11     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart)
I/flutter (31392): #12     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart)
I/flutter (31392): #13     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart)
I/flutter (31392): #14     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart)
I/flutter (31392): #15     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart)
I/flutter (31392): #16     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart)
I/flutter (31392): #17     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart)
I/flutter (31392): #18     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart)
I/flutter (31392): #19     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart)
I/flutter (31392): #20     StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart)
I/flutter (31392): #21     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart)
I/flutter (31392): #22     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart)
I/flutter (31392): #23     ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart)
I/flutter (31392): #24     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart)
I/flutter (31392): #25     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart)
I/flutter (31392): #26     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart)
I/flutter (31392): #27     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart)
I/flutter (31392): #28     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart)
I/flutter (31392): #29     StatelessElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart)
I/flutter (31392): #30     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart)
I/flutter (31392): #31     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart)
I/flutter (31392): #32     StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart)
I/flutter (31392): #33     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart)
I/flutter (31392): #34     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart)
I/flutter (31392): #35     StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart)
I/flutter (31392): #36     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart)
I/flutter (31392): #37     StatelessElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart)
I/flutter (31392): #38     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart)
I/flutter (31392): #39     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart)
I/flutter (31392): #40     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart)
I/flutter (31392): #41     StatelessElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart)
I/flutter (31392): #42     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart)
I/flutter (31392): #43     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart)
I/flutter (31392): #44     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart)
I/flutter (31392): #45     StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart)
I/flutter (31392): #46     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart)
I/flutter (31392): #47     ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart)
I/flutter (31392): #48     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart)
I/flutter (31392): #49     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart)
I/flutter (31392): #50     BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart)
I/flutter (31392): #51     WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart)
I/flutter (31392): #52     RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart)
I/flutter (31392): #53     SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart)
I/flutter (31392): #54     SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart)
I/flutter (31392): #55     SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart)
I/flutter (31392): #59     _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart)
I/flutter (31392): #60     PlatformDispatcher._drawFrame (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart)
I/flutter (31392): #61     _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart)
I/flutter (31392): (elided 3 frames from dart:async)
I/flutter (31392): Another exception was thrown: Instance of 'DiagnosticsProperty<void>'
I/flutter (31392): Another exception was thrown: Instance of 'DiagnosticsProperty<void>'
I/flutter (31392): Another exception was thrown: Instance of 'DiagnosticsProperty<void>'
I/flutter (31392): Another exception was thrown: Instance of 'DiagnosticsProperty<void>'
I/flutter (31392): Another exception was thrown: Instance of 'DiagnosticsProperty<void>'
```

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem,And I fix it with change this code in flutter-quill-4.1.1/src/widgets/image.dart, like this

```
bool isImageBase64(String imageUrl) {
return !imageUrl.startsWith('http') ;//&& isBase64(imageUrl);
}
```

I found isBase64 be casue stack overflow.grey screen in release.

I can make sure my editor only use base64 image,so you need fix isBase64 function in your code.

try reduce or get subString to regex.match.